# Is it possible to show password reset email success in user password page?

Tags: 7, users

I am completely exhausted trying to find out a solution for this simple problem.

I am intending to put a "Forgot Password" in my Drupal site and wants a confirmation when the form emails the password to the user.

For instance, I go to this link http://www.some.com/user/password for the "Forgot Password" link.

when I enter the username or password, it just doesn't show anything and just redirects to the homepage. I intend to change that and want to show the confirmation that an email has been successfully sent.

Any idea how I can do this?

### What I tried

I tried creating a page--user--password.tpl.php but it doesn't allow me to make any changes. I am not sure where the values are coming in the form.

Comment: Have you installed some module the override login functionality? The default behavior is set a notification message, "'Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address." and redirect to /user.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I installed Login Toboggan. Do you it's happening due to that module?

Comment: Perhaps, I know there's a couple of redirection options for 403's & on login. It's worth disabling and trying password reset to test if that's the issue. Something must be controlling the redirect path.

Answer (score 1):

By default, drupal_set_message() is set and displayed on form submission when a new password is emailed. It's possible LoginToboggan is interfering with this but I haven't encountered that in my use of it.

Alternatively, if you cannot resolve the issue, you can use hook_form_alter() to create your own submission handler on the password reset form, and use drupal_set_message() to re-show the message (or any custom message you provide) on the form.

```
function MYMODULE_password_reset_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_handler';
}

function my_custom_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('An email has been sent with instructions to reset your password.');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's definetly a module or something acting with the login behavior.

On a brand new Drupal 7 install, if you use the reset link on /user/passsword, it redirects to /user and show the following system message : Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.

You'll need to desactivate modules which could interfere and check for other things like Rules or whatever.

Comment: Welcome to drupal.SE! Sorry to say, but your 'answer' appears to be rather a 'comment' than an actual 'answer' since it provides little to no information that qould be useful to answer the question. Please try to provide some more actual information about possible solutions – be it module names, code snippets, links or the like. Thank you!